# AjaxResponse in build() custom block

Tags: blocks, ajax

I want to add an AjaxResponse in build() custom block

```
public function build() {
    $build['content'] = $this->getContent('field_header_text');

    return $build;
}
```

This basic code works and I want to add an AjaxResponse to add a CSS class on specific div like that

```
public function build() {
  $build['content'] = $this->getContent('field_header_text');

  $ajaxResponse = new AjaxResponse();
  $ajaxResponse->addCommand(new InvokeCommand("#main", 'addClass', ['success']));

  return $build;
}
```

Any idea?
Thank

Comment: You can only return an Ajax response when the client is sending an Ajax request. Then both, the added class and the updated content have to be Ajax commands.